# Why does compiling my XCode project work with Apple-(B)uild and fail to compile with Apple-(U)nit tests?

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, xcode4.6

When using XCode 4.6, my question is that I want to know the difference between using the Apple-B (compile my source) versus the Apple-U which I thought is compile my source and run unit tests command.

Why does the former build successfully and the latter not? My error doesn't even occur within the test files, its within a source file that should be compiled in both cases.

Comment: Ah, it might be that its a different target being built in the case of Apple-U (i.e. the Tests target)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably right with your comment. Try this:

- Select the file that the build error is related to
- Make sure that the File Inspector is visible (Option + Command + 1, or View > Utilities > Show File Inspector)
- In the File Inspector there is a section titled "Target Membership"
- Make sure that your file is checked for your unit test target

If your project uses folders (folder icons are blue) instead of groups (folder icons are yellow) then you must select a top-level folder to see the "Target Membership" section in File Inspector. In this case you do not set target membership on individual files, but on a top-level folder. All files and subfolders inherit target membership from their top-level folder.

Comment: Spot on thanks! I'm suprised that xcode doesn't naturally include the .m file as part of the build for the unit test project. Although I've been messing around with the test target loads trying to understand its structure!

Comment: @TheSenator As far as I know the unit test target has no special significance to Xcode, so managing the target is completely up to you. Although a little help by the IDE would certainly be nice, it is difficult to strike a balance: Too much "helpful" interference by the IDE and it becomes annoying. I'm not sure what you do not understand about the test target structure, but you certainly know where you can ask a question :-)